# How to add this library (web3) and use on my html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node project where I am trying to use web3 on a simple html page so users can write something to a simple smart contract. Step 1 I am trying is simply to have access to the web3 object in a JavaScript file called by main.html.

Here is the folder structure:

```
index.js
package.json
main.html (uses main.js)
assets/
    js/
        main.js
```

The following code I use to get started with ganache test network on my computer:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3 ( "http://localhost:7545" )
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    console.log("Connected to web3");
    return true;
    
  }
  alert("Error - could not connect via web3.js");
  return false;

}
```

However when I paste this code to the top of `assets/js/main.js` I get the following:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at main.js:5`

So I can't even use the `require` package, let alone the `web3` package, both of which I have both installed via `npm install`.

However, when I paste the above web3 code in `index.js` it doesn't seem to give an error:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3 ( "http://localhost:7545" )
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    console.log("Connected to web3");
    return true;
    
  }
  alert("Error - could not connect via web3.js");
  return false;

}

app.use(express.static("./assets"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //res.send('Hello World!')
  res.sendFile('./main.html', { root: __dirname });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I want to use `web3` functionality on `main.html` with `main.js`, as the user would be filling out a form, hitting a button, then I'd use `web3` functionality to write something to my simple contract.

But I think I am not understanding `node.js` project layout and structure. Given the use case above, how should I proceed? When I put the `web3` starter code in `index.js`, I don't know how to access the `web3` object in `main.js`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pure js file in your .html.
Add the script in your header and only instanciate the Web3 class:  `new Web3 ( "http://localhost:7545" )`,

```
<script src="https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/v1.2.11/dist/web3.min.js></script>
```

Comment: Hmm OK I see. I already have `npm install web3` so I can use it in `index.js`. So best practice is I should do this include as well to use it in `main.js` which interacts with `main.html`? So then I didn't need to `npm install`? Sure I'll try it out, just seems a bit weird.

Comment: Also when I try doing `new Web3(..)` in `index.js` then load the html page, I open the console and don't seem to have access to this web3 object.

Comment: The script is only going to work into the client side. If you need to use it in server side you need to use `require` and `npm install`. `index.js` and `main.js` is your server side.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so I need both client and server side then? High level, all I want to do is letter users add some text in a box, hit submit, then this text is written to my smart contract (also the same html page pulls existing text from the smart contract). So do I need server side at all? What exactly is the difference in functionality for either? Thx so much for the help so far:)

Comment: I do not know very well web3 lib, but with a quick look into the docs I think you can do it server side or client side, is your choice.